# whenever i run this code its shows me the requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool error

Tags: python

whenever i run this code its shows me the requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool error

```
import requests
def download(url):
    get_response = requests.get(url)
    file_name =url.split("/")[-1]
    print(file_name)
    with open("sample.txt", "wb") as out:
         out.write(get_response.content)
download("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ca/76/0b/ca760b70976b52578da88e06973af542.jpg")
```

***And this is the error***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "download_file.py", line 10, in <module>
    download("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ca/76/0b/ca760b70976b52578da88e06973af542.jpg")
  File "download_file.py", line 4, in download
    get_response = requests.get(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='i.pinimg.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /originals/ca/76/0b/ca760b70976b52578da88e06973af542.jpg (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f6bebc83350>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',))
```

Comment: You are having a network problem. And BTW Python 2 is outdated, it's time to update.

Comment: My internet and python version is fine

Comment: Check your network connection!!

Answer (score 1):

This is a internet problem check your wifi, and make sure the URL you wrote is correct.